# Multiple user Login where multiple user can login and get redirected to respective pages

Tags: django

I have four types of user like buyer seller organizer and staff. So i would like to know how to implement multiple type login in django

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser

    class Seller(AbstractBaseUser):
    """
    Custom user class.
    """
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True, db_index=True)
    joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_seller = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Buyer(AbstractBaseUser):
    """
    Custom user class.
    """
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True, db_index=True)
    joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_buyer = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Staff(AbstractBaseUser):
    """
    Custom user class.
    """
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True, db_index=True)
    joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Organizer(AbstractBaseUser):
    """
    Custom user class.
    """
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True, db_index=True)
    joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_organizer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```